# Problemas para Setear un JTextfield con Document y DocumentFilter en Java

Tags: java, jtextfield

Tengo un campo de Texto `JTextField` el cual tiene texto por defecto que sirve como placeholder

El problema es que al ganar el Foco debiera de Borrar el texto y permitir escribir

`FocusGained`

```
 private void txtSearch_PuestosFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtSearch_Puestos.setText("");
    txtSearch_Puestos.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    Document _document = txtSearch_Puestos.getDocument();
    DocumentFilter _documentFilter = new FilterTextAndUppercase(FilterTextAndUppercase.onlyText);
    ((AbstractDocument) _document).setDocumentFilter(_documentFilter);
}
```

Lo anterior me funciona la primera vez, pero a la segunda vez que obtengo el foco, me deja el texto que tengo como placeholder.

Dejo Código de `LostFocus`

```
private void txtSearch_PuestosFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (txtSearch_Puestos.getText().equals("")) {
        txtSearch_Puestos.setText("Buscar Puestos...");
        txtSearch_Puestos.setForeground(colorSearch);
    }
}
```

**Clase FilterTextAndUppercase**

```
package _class;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;


public class FilterTextAndUppercase extends DocumentFilter {

//Variable para condicionar si se acepta solo numeros
public static final char onlyNumbers = 'N';
//Variable para condicionar si se acepta solo texto
public static final char onlyText = 'T';
//Variable para condicionar se se acepta alfanumericos
public static final char textAndNumbers = 'A';
//Variable que sirve para no condicionar y aceptar todos los caracteres
public static final char defaultWrite = '*';
//Variable que sirve de almacenamiento de las variables condicionales
private char filterEntry;
//Variable que limita el numero de Caracteres
private int lengthString = 0;
//Variable Toolkit
Toolkit _toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

/**
 * Constructor sin parámetros Este constructor inicia la condicional como
 * default aceptando cualquier caracter
 */
public FilterTextAndUppercase() {
    filterEntry = defaultWrite;
}

/**
 * Constructor que recibe la condicional para validar los tipos de datos que
 * se deseán, sin la necesidad de restringir el tamaño del texto
 *
 * @param filterEntry recibe el tipo de condicion que se realizara
 */
public FilterTextAndUppercase(char filterEntry) {
    this.filterEntry = filterEntry;
}

/**
 * Constructor que recibe la condicional de los tipos de caracteres que se
 * aceptaran, asi como el numero de caracteres
 *
 * @param filterEntry recibe el tipo de condicion que se realizara
 * @param lenghtString recibe cuantos caracteres permitira escribir
 */
public FilterTextAndUppercase(char filterEntry, int lenghtString) {
    this.filterEntry = filterEntry;
    this.lengthString = lenghtString;
}

/**
 * Método redefinido que remplaza el texto
 *
 * @param fb
 * @param offset
 * @param length
 * @param text
 * @param attrs
 * @throws BadLocationException
 */
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    //Obtiene los datos del objeto
    Document _document = fb.getDocument();
    //Obtiene el numero de caracteres del Objeto
    int lengthActually = _document.getLength();
    //Valida el texto
    if (validate(text)) {
        //Valida el tamaño de la condicional de caracteres si se envia un limite o no
        if (this.lengthString == 0 || lengthActually < lengthString) {
            //Muestra el texto y lo cambia a mayúsculas
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Método redefinido que inserta el texto
 *
 * @param fb
 * @param offset
 * @param string
 * @param attr
 * @throws BadLocationException
 */
@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    //Compara que el texto sea distinto a nulo
    if (string != null) {
        Document _document = fb.getDocument();
        int lengthActually = _document.getLength();
        //Valida el texto con la condicional que se le haya enviado
        if (validate(string)) {
            //Valida si se le restringio numero de caracteres al texto
            if (this.lengthString == 0 || lengthActually < lengthString) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Metodo redefinido remover
 *
 * @param fb
 * @param offset
 * @param length
 * @throws BadLocationException
 */
@Override
public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
    super.remove(fb, offset, length); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

/**
 * Metodo que valida el texto segun la condicional
 *
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
private boolean validate(String value) {
    //Obtiene un arreglo de caracteres segun la palabra
    char[] letters = value.toCharArray();
    //La variable valid funciona como bandera 
    boolean valid = false;
    //Se recorre los caracteres del texto enviado
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        //Compara el tipo de condicional que se establecio por caracter
        switch (filterEntry) {
            //Caracter que sea numero
            case onlyNumbers:
                //Compara el caracter y lo valida
                if (Character.isDigit(letters[i])) {
                    valid = true;
                } else {
                    //Emitirá un sonido en caso de no cumplir la condicion
                    _toolkit.beep();
                }
                break;
            case onlyText:
                //Compara el caracter y lo valida
                if (Character.isLetter(letters[i])) {
                    valid = true;
                } else {
                    //Emitirá un sonido en caso de no cumplir la condicion
                    _toolkit.beep();
                }
                break;

            case textAndNumbers:
                //Compara el caracter y lo valida
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(letters[i])) {
                    valid = true;
                } else {
                    //Emitirá un sonido en caso de no cumplir la condicion
                    _toolkit.beep();
                }
                break;
            //Si es defaultWrite aceptara cualquier caracter
            case defaultWrite:
                valid = true;
                break;

            default:
                valid = false;
                break;
        }
        if (valid) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return valid;
}

}
```

El problema es ¿Cómo puedo setear el campo vacío y luego volver a poner el texto que por default tiene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

```
 try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        txtSearch_Departamentos.getDocument().remove(0, txtSearch_Departamentos.getText().length());
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmDepartamentos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Remueve el largo de la cadena de caracteres que el `JTextField` hasta la posicion 0